# Last modified field for user profile?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a plugin or a known way to track user profile changes and save a last modified date in Wordpress?

I tried with ACF, but it doesn't have an option to auto update this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @ViniciusPires - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! You should review our "[ask]" page in the [help] for some tips on writing a good question. Vague questions (especially those that neglect to show research and effort on behalf of the asker) tend to receive vague answers. Also note that questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes or asking for recommendations for such items are presently [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, @bosco. The thing is that I already made my research, and I didn't find any plugin :/ I'm also asking for a way, being it a plugin or some code I have to write to make this possible. I also listed what I have tried. Can you point anything else how I can improve my question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem actually makes for a pretty good project to get started with plugin development. Read up on [plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) and check out the [user metadata functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), which let you store and retrieve arbitrary data relating to a user. A good place to update your "last modified" metadata would be the [`'profile_update'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) action =]

Comment: If you run into some questions while implementing such a plugin, they'll definitely be on-topic for our community. If you're not interested in WordPress development, you may want to try asking for the plugin recommendation over at [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Thank you, @bosco! These pages are exactly what I was looking for. Can you turn your comments into an answer? I'll mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) and [Metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) APIs to attach some functionality to [the `'profile_update'` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update) such that whenever a user's profile information receives an update, custom user-metadata is set to the time of the update:

```
function wpse216609_update_profile_modified( $user_id ) {
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wpse216609_profile_updated', current_time( 'mysql' ) );
}

add_action( 'profile_update', 'wpse216609_update_profile_modified' );
```